# Add CSS Class to Image in qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, css, image, class, qooxdoo

Code qooxdoo:

```
var cImage = new qx.ui.container.Composite().set({
        layout: new qx.ui.layout.VBox,
    });

var imgName = "photo.jpg",
    image   =  new qx.ui.basic.Image( imgName )
    ;

cImage.add( image );
```

I'm trying to add a class to an image to work with :hover and :before.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the content element and add the class there:

```
image.getContentElement().addClass("myCssClass")
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addClass'

Answer (score 0):

The final solution:

```
var el = image.getContentElement().getDomElement();
if ( el.classList ) el.classList.add( className );
else el.className += ' ' + className;
```

Or... using jQuery:

```
var el = image.getContentElement().getDomElement();
$(el).addClass( className );
```